# is there a way to pass session variable to a new tab when a link is clicked

Tags: php, html, jquery

here is the link used to open  new tab feature

```
 <a target="_blank" href="task.php" ><i class="fas fa-eye fa-lg fa-fw"></i></a>
```

Comment: Yes there is, but you need to explain from where you want to get the session variable, and where it shall be placed in the link

Comment: If the page is on the same domain as the current page - which it would be given your example - why do you need to pass a session value using the URL? If it's in the session you can just access it on the next page...?

Answer (score 1):

```
<a target="_blank" href="task.php?**someVariable='.$_SESSION["someVariable"]"** **target="_blank"**><i class="fas fa-eye fa-lg fa-fw"></i></a>
```

**UPDATE** Including explanation from comments:

If you need to pass any variable in your URL just add `?<myVariable>=<myValue>`.

To open a link in a new tab just add `target="_blank"` in the anchor tag.

Comment: This needs an explanation of the components. I suggest quoting original question code for reference when discussing changes you suggest above.

Comment: if you need to pass any variable in your URL just add '?' then variable name then '=' variable value. The second part is open in a new tab just add target="_blank" in the anchor tag.

Comment: FTFY - Try and keep any improvements to an answer/question within that answer/question post. Comments get hidden as more people respond.

PS: don't forget formatting makes a big difference on user experience.
[Check out the markup editing options!](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)